# Is there a complete list of Active Directory attributes, and a mapping to LDAP?

Tags: c++, powershell, active-directory, ldap

I'm querying Active Directory from c++, using the LDAP interface (using iads.h).
I notice there is a difference in attributenames for Users.

When executing in Powershell

```
 Get-ADUser sih -Properties *
```

there is an attribute EmailAddress. When querying the AD from C++, the attribute EmailAddress is not found. Mail is however found, both with Powershell and C++.

Is there any mapping, or why are some attributes present in Powershell and not in the C++ interface for the User object?

Note: when using Active Directory Explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/adexplorer.aspx), the attribute EmailAddress is not shown either for users. It seems that all attribute shown here can be fetched from C++.

I'm looking for a mapping from AD to LDAP, to offer the possibility to fetch all values from AD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are two different questions.

For a mapping between internal attribute names and LDAP display names: 
It's called the Schema :-)

Retrieve all objects with `objectClass=attributeSchema` and compare the `adminDisplayName` and `lDAPDisplayName` attribute values:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectClass -eq "attributeSchema"' -SearchBase 'CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=forest,DC=tld' -Properties adminDisplayName,lDAPDisplayName |Select-Object adminDisplayName,lDAPDisplayName
```

---

For a mapping between the user-friendly property names in the PowerShell ActiveDirectory module (like `EmailAddress`) and the LDAP display names (like `mail`), these are hard-coded as internal constants in the `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.dll` assembly.

Here's how you can retrieve them using a bit of reflection magic:

```
# Import the Active Directory module:
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Now, obtain a reference to the assembly itself:
$ADAssembly = [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADEntity].Assembly

# Now we'll need to retrieve the internal class that defines the constants:
$LDAPAttributes = $ADAssembly.GetType('Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.LdapAttributes')

# Then use GetFields() to retrieve the internal constants
$LDAPNameConstants = $LDAPAttributes.GetFields('Static,NonPublic') |Where-Object {$_.IsLiteral}

# Finally build a hashtable with the Property Names -> LDAP Name mapping
$LDAPPropertyMap = @{}
$LDAPNameConstants |ForEach-Object {
    $LDAPPropertyMap[$_.Name] = $_.GetRawConstantValue()
}
```

`$LDAPPropertyMap` now contains your mappings

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell AD cmdlets do more than just returning the bare attributes of a user. To make account information easier to use they create additional properties, some just with a more "speaking" name (e.g. `mail`→`EmailAddress`), others with the raw data converted to a more digestible format (e.g. `pwdLastSet`→`PasswordLastSet`, `accountExpires`→`AccountExpirationDate`) or to show particular flags (e.g. `Enabled`, which indicates whether the flag `ACCOUNTDISABLE` is set in the [`userAccountControl`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144) attribute).